# Making polygon cut off at ocean using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, administrative-boundaries

I have a polygon for an administrative boundary, which is on the coast of an island. The admin boundary currently wraps around the coastline polygon I have, but I want it to just stop and not show the border overlapping the coastline.

I have attached an illustration below of what I want to do. I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options:

1. Convert you admin boundary, which I assume is a polygon into a polyline then edit the polyline by splitting it at the coast and deleting out the coastal section.
2. Duplicate the coastal boundary layer in your map, drag it to the top in the Contents pane and then symbolise it with an empty fill. This approach ensures your admin boundary remains as is but its coastal section is drawn over by the coast line.

**UPDATE**

Having now told the full story in your comments below here is a model that will automate the effect you desire; to allow you to have different line widths, thick for admin, thin for coast. For the record you should be more descriptive in your request for help when your problem has any restrictions, line width in your case.

The model requires you to have an advance license because of the tools used and the results are shown below.

[image: Model]

The select layer by Location is using the relationship of *Have their center in* to use the split coastline for selecting admin boundaries at the coast which are deleted out.

[image: Output]

Comment: I've been doing the first point you suggested. The problem is that I'm dealing with vast amounts of admin boundary data (i.e., an entire country's first level administrative divisions) that would take me ~30 mins to do. I was hoping there was a quicker way.

Comment: I think you can do step 2 only: if you have the landmass, you can duplicate it and put this layer on top, with an empty fill and thick enough outline to cover the administrative boundary.

Comment: The problem is that I have a thick admin boundary and an extremely thin coastline, so I'll have to sacrifice one.

Comment: @Berrely see updated answer